# Azure Cosmos DB SQL Like, prepared statements

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Does the Azure Cosmos DB SQL Like API provide the equivalent of prepared statements to avoid SQL injection? The quick start example to do not cover that and I seems to find no documentation on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you just need to use the SDK method to [call the query with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-parameterized-queries#examples).

```
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE f.lastName = @lastName AND f.address.state = @addressState",
    "parameters": [
        {"name": "@lastName", "value": "Wakefield"},
        {"name": "@addressState", "value": "NY"},
    ]
}
```

or maybe you are talking about [stored procedures](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/tree/master/samples/stored-procedures)?