# Building CosmosDB Query strings with escaping

Tags: java, sql, azure, security, azure-cosmosdb

I want to build a cosmosdb sql query, because I'm using a rest interface, which accepts SQL querys (don't ask why, I can't change that :( )...

Now I want to build that query with some parameters, which affects the WHERE clause.
I think it is a good idea to escape these parameters, to prevent sql injection.

But I just found these way to build a query:

```java
var param = new SqlParameter();
param.add("@test", "here some string to inject");
var query = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT @test FROM table", param);
```

Now I could do sql calls to the cosmos's without sql injection. But I don't want this. I just want to get the query string.
But I need the full query from "query". But there seems to be just the method `query.getQueryText()`. But this just returns the string "SELECT @test FROM table".

Do know a workaround for me? Or maybe just a good package I can use to to my own string escapes.

T

Comment: I found the information that this escalation stuff doesn't happen on client site. It happens in the dbms. So I need a rest interface, where I can pass the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I found the information that this escalation stuff doesn't happen on client site. It happens in the dbms. So I need a rest interface, where I can pass the parameters.

[Azure Cosmos DB SQL Like, prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526653/azure-cosmos-db-sql-like-prepared-statements)

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, too. 
But one problem is that I need to change the ObjectMapper. I don't know how t change the default ObjectMapper just for one method. So I can't use the class itself as return type. 
I changed it to String and I'm parsing the class with an object mapper to a string (writeValueAsString). The problem is swagger can't detect the original return type. So it just says the Endpoint returns String. Does somebody has a solution for that?